# View cookies on Android Firefox?

Tags: android, firefox, cookies

I want to view cookies on Firefox on Android to troubleshoot a website development issue. I've done a search through Firefox's interface, and found a number of matches about deleting cookies, but nothing about viewing them.

Is there a Firefox add-on for Android that allows me to view the cookies?

Comment: You might want to look into [remote debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android) to get access to all the usual development tools.

Comment: Searching all sites for [cookies] [Android] Firefox returns this question as the **only** useful hit. The newest versions of Firefox Android doesn't permit viewing Cookies or *modification* (though with root or adb you *could* copy the file and modify it on a Desktop (using SQL Lite) and copy the file back). One thing, not an "answer", is you can delete **all** your Cookies as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlKQz.jpg - This might not fix a "development issue", it might fix an "access issue"; hopefully this information assists you and future viewers.